# Similar triangles and cross section integrals.

Tags: calculus, geometry

I am reading this in my text:

[image]

Why do they say that $x = \frac{s}{2}$? In similar triangles, aren't the sides themselves supposed to be proportional? Why do they do this intermediate step using $\frac{s}{2}$?

Also, I forget, in an equilateral triangle, how do you know that the height bisects a side?

Comment: " in an equilateral triangle, how do you know that the height bisects a side?" - Anything else, will destroy the symmetry. For e.g.: If the height divides the base $c$, in the ratio of 2:1, then you can clearly see that the corresponding sides $a,b$ are not necessarily identical. If the sides were identical in all aspects, then the height should bisect.

Comment: They do not say, $x = s/2$. They are using similarity relationship between two triangles - one of them has base $x$ and other has base $h$

Answer (score 1):

> Why do they say that $x=s/2$? In similar triangles, aren't the sides themselves supposed to be proportional? Why do they do this intermediate step using $s/2$?

That is not what they are saying. They are saying that when using similar triangles the scale by which one side has increased is the same scale by which all sides increase. So $\frac{x}h$ and $\frac {s/2}{L/2}$ should be the same, since they represent the same scale factor.

> Also, I forget, in an equilateral triangle, how do you know that the height bisects a side?

The height is given by dropping a perpendicular down from one of the vertices of the triangle. Since we are looking at an equilateral triangle, each internal angle is $60^\circ$, so by dropping this perpendicular we have split the triangle into two triangles with internal angles $30^\circ,60^\circ,90^\circ$. Two of their sides are the same and all of their angles are the same, so the remaining side must also be equal. So we have cut the base in half.